# std::out_of_range on static int variable

Tags: c++, c++11, variables, static, int

I am using a static variable as a make-shift timer in a small dos-based game (course project).  The variable keeps track of the number of turns before a status effect wears off.  Here is the code:

```
for (auto &i : v) // <-- code that calls enemyAttack
    enemyAttack(i, p, str, i.attack);
break;

void enemyAttack(Enemy &e, playerObject &p, std::array<std::string, NUM_MESSAGES> &str, void(*a)(playerObject &p, std::array<std::string, NUM_MESSAGES> &str)) {
    int die = rand() % 100 + 1;
    int d = 1;

    a(p, str); // <-- Call function which causes the error

    ...
}

void batAttack(playerObject &p, std::array<std::string, NUM_MESSAGES> &str) {
    static int time = 2;
    static bool bit = false;

    if (rand() % 10 < CHANCE_OF_STATUS_EFFECT && !bit) {
        p.damage /= 2;
        str[STATUS] += "WEAKENED ";
        bit = true;
    }
    else if (time == 0) {
        p.damage *= 2;
        str[STATUS].replace(str[STATUS].find("WEAKENED ", 0), 9, "");

        time = 2;  // <-- error
        bit = false;
    }
    else if (bit) {
        time--;
    }
}
```

I receive an std::out_of_range error at the line `time = 2;` inside the second condition.  This function is called via a function pointer from a primary attack function.  The error seems to be random and MSVS reports all variables having the value they should have when the error occurs.

Comment: What is `STATUS`? What is `NUM_MESSAGES`? What are their values? Please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Also, what do you think happens if `str[STATUS].find("WEAKENED ", 0)` doesn't find the string you're looking for? Even if something is supposed to "never happen", it always will!

Comment: You don't by chance have multiple threads that would be trying to access this static variable at the same time do you?

Comment: This is a course project for an intro programming course, we haven't gone over threading yet.  STATUS is part of an enum and NUM_MESSAGES is a const int whose value is the number of values in the enumeration which STATUS is a member of.

Comment: But what are their *values?* Though I rather believe that it's the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) call that fails and it returns [`npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) leading to [`replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) throwing the exception. Use the debugger to check the value of `str[STATUS]`, I'll bet that it doesn't contain the sub-string `"WEAKENED "`.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
str[STATUS].replace(str[STATUS].find("WEAKENED ", 0), 9, "");
```

Is just a disaster waiting to happen. Let look at the inner find first.

```
str[STATUS].find("WEAKENED ", 0)
```

Your using the value "WEAKENED " twice in the short program when you do this often enough you will have spelling errors, therefore its better to use a named value here so there is no chance of making mistakes.

```
constexpr const char *WeakenedStr = "WEAKENED ";
```

and then use

```
str[STATUS].find(WeakenedStr , 0)
```

Secondly this could fail, if the string is not found it returns 'npos' (which is currently -1). So we need to test that too

```
auto pos = str[STATUS].find("WEAKENED ", 0);
if (pos != std::string::npos)
  str[STATUS].replace(pos, 9, "");
```

Next is the '9' which is a magic number, that too should be a named value

```
constexpr const char *WeakenedStr = "WEAKENED ";
const int WeakenedStrLen = strlen(WeakenedStr); // strlen is sadly not constexpr.
```

Giving

```
auto pos = str[STATUS].find("WEAKENED ", 0);
if (pos != std::string::npos)
  str[STATUS].replace(pos, WeakenedStrLen, "");
```

Note: untested code, bug will occur.

Comment: IT WORKED!!  Thank you!  I'm just two days out from the due date and was starting to worry.